# IEEE 754 to decimal. I'm not sure if I did this corectly

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, cpu-architecture, ieee-754

> If a number in the format of the single precision is shown as hex
>   7F41F000, determine its numeric value.

So I converted it to binary: 0111 1111 0100 0001 1111 0000 0000 0000

By looking at binary representation of given number I find following:

s (sign) = 0

exp = 1111 1110 = 254(decimal)

mantissa = 1000 0011 1110 0000 0000 0000

So doing some calculations i get that

e = 254 - 127 = 127

m (decimal part) = 0.51513671875

and formula for final result is -1^s x (1 + m) x 2^e which is **1.51513671875 x 2^127**

Since I listened lecture about this 2 days ago I am not entirely sure if I did it right.

What I am asking is confirmation of correctness or saying what I did wrong and where exactly, I would appreciate if anyone gives me points on this topic, as far i know, this is IEEE 754 standard for floating point computation.

[Oh and I included better written format of this problem. Check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa9G8.png)

Comment: There's an online IEEE754 converter: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.  You can enter bit patterns in hex or binary, and it decodes it.  Or you can enter decimal values and it rounds to the nearest single-precision bit-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `(-1)^sign bit*(1+fraction)* 2^( exponent - bias)`

And you did exactly the same so this is correct.

I write up this formula because it reminds you of the bias correction always.

Comment: Hey mate, that's what I did, as you can see, I've done those calculations before